# If the S-Box is given. How to calculate the affine transformation matrix?

Tags: aes, block-cipher, s-boxes

## Example using SAGE

sage: sr = mq.SR(1, 1, 1, 8, gf2=True)

sage: S = sr.sbox(); S

(99, 124, 119, 123, 242, 107, 111, 197, 48, 1, 103, 43, 254, 215, 171, 118, 202, 130, 201, 125, 250, 89, 71, 240, 173, 212, 162, 175, 156, 164, 114, 192, 183, 253, 147, 38, 54, 63, 247, 204, 52, 165, 229, 241, 113, 216, 49, 21, 4, 199, 35, 195, 24, 150, 5, 154, 7, 18, 128, 226, 235, 39, 178, 117, 9, 131, 44, 26, 27, 110, 90, 160, 82, 59, 214, 179, 41, 227, 47, 132, 83, 209, 0, 237, 32, 252, 177, 91, 106, 203, 190, 57, 74, 76, 88, 207, 208, 239, 170, 251, 67, 77, 51, 133, 69, 249, 2, 127, 80, 60, 159, 168, 81, 163, 64, 143, 146, 157, 56, 245, 188, 182, 218, 33, 16, 255, 243, 210, 205, 12, 19, 236, 95, 151, 68, 23, 196, 167, 126, 61, 100, 93, 25, 115, 96, 129, 79, 220, 34, 42, 144, 136, 70, 238, 184, 20, 222, 94, 11, 219, 224, 50, 58, 10, 73, 6, 36, 92, 194, 211, 172, 98, 145, 149, 228, 121, 231, 200, 55, 109, 141, 213, 78, 169, 108, 86, 244, 234, 101, 122, 174, 8, 186, 120, 37, 46, 28, 166, 180, 198, 232, 221, 116, 31, 75, 189, 139, 138, 112, 62, 181, 102, 72, 3, 246, 14, 97, 53, 87, 185, 134, 193, 29, 158, 225, 248, 152, 17, 105, 217, 142, 148, 155, 30, 135, 233, 206, 85, 40, 223, 140, 161, 137, 13, 191, 230, 66, 104, 65, 153, 45, 15, 176, 84, 187, 22)

sage: sr.lin_matrix()

[1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]

[0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]

[0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0]

[0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1]

[1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]

[1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1]

[1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1]

[1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1]

## If S-Box = (51, 236, 224, 63, 203, 20, 24, 199,83, 140, 128, 95, 171, 116, 120, 167, 142, 81, 93, 130, 118, 169, 165, 122, 238, 49, 61, 226, 22, 201, 197, 26, 210, 13, 1, 222, 42, 245, 249, 38, 178, 109, 97, 190, 74, 149, 153, 70,111, 176, 188, 99, 151, 72, 68, 155, 15, 208, 220, 3, 247, 40, 36, 251, 195, 28, 16, 207, 59, 228, 232, 55, 163, 124, 112, 175, 91, 132, 136, 87, 126, 161, 173, 114, 134, 89, 85, 138, 30, 193, 205, 18, 230, 57, 53, 234, 34, 253, 241, 46, 218, 5, 9,214, 66, 157, 145, 78, 186, 101, 105, 182, 159, 64, 76, 147, 103, 184, 180, 107, 255, 32, 44, 243, 7, 216, 212, 11, 127, 160, 172, 115, 135, 88, 84, 139, 31, 192, 204, 19, 231, 56, 52, 235, 194, 29, 17, 206, 58, 229, 233, 54, 162, 125, 113, 174, 90, 133, 137, 86, 158, 65, 77, 146, 102, 185, 181, 106, 254, 33, 45, 242, 6, 217, 213, 10, 35, 252, 240, 47, 219, 4, 8, 215, 67, 156, 144, 79, 187, 100, 104, 183, 143, 80, 92, 131, 119, 168, 164, 123, 239, 48, 60, 227, 23, 200, 196, 27, 50, 237, 225, 62, 202, 21, 25, 198, 82, 141, 129, 94, 170, 117, 121, 166, 110, 177, 189, 98, 150, 73, 69, 154, 14, 209, 221, 2, 246, 41, 37, 250, 211, 12, 0, 223, 43, 244, 248, 39, 179, 108, 96, 191, 75, 148, 152, 71) see [How can one construct the weakest S-box ever?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51017/how-can-one-construct-the-weakest-s-box-ever)

What is the affine transformation matrix?

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - It is hard to parse what you are asking. Consider using the "edit" button to try and clarify your question; Doing so will help you get a better reception to your question and more/better quality answers.

Comment: The most useless s-box would be the one with no finite field inversion

Comment: unclear and unorganized question, the affine matrix of second sbox. what is realation between the reference places and the question

Comment: Sage has also Question&answer [site](https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/).